# ASP.NET MVC Get inherited class data in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I am very new to c# and OOP and MVC and am struggling with getting the data from an inherited class in MVC View. I am probably doing this all wrong.

I have for example:

```
public class TasksViewModel
{
    public Tasks tasks;
        public TaskViewModel()
        {
            this.tasks = new Tasks();
        }
    }
}
```

I then have (simplified):

```
public class BaseTask    
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}

public class WorkTasks : BaseTask
{
    public String Company { get; set; }
}

public class HomeTasks : BaseTask
{
    public String UserName{ get; set; }
}

public class Tasks
{

    public List<BaseTask> taskslist { get; set; }
    public Tasks()
    {
         taskslist = getAllTasks();
    }

    public List<BaseTask> getAllTasks()
    {


           //get data
        List<BaseTask> tempTasks = new List<BaseTask>();
        if (taskType == "Work")
        {
            WorkTask work = new WorkTask();
            work.id = id;
            work.Description = description;
            work.Company = company;
            tempTasks.Add(work)
        }
        else
        {
            HomeTask home = new HomeTask();
            home.id = id;
            home.Description = description;
            home.UserName = name;
            tempTasks.Add(home)
        }
...
        return tempTasks;

}
```

I set the model as Tasks and in my view I just iterate through them

```
@foreach(var item in Model.tasks.taskslist)
{
    <p>@item.Description</p>
}
```

this works just fine and I can get the description and Id, but I can't get the Company or UserName from the tasks inherited from BaseTask. The data I get from item is:

```
>id
>Description
>Namespace.WorkTasks
```

however I can't access WorkTasks or HomeTasks.

I can check that the item is a WorkTask or a HomeTask with

```
if (item.GetType().Name.Equals("WorkTasks"))
{
}
```

and I tried

```
item.WorkTasks.Company
```

but this just gives an error: Tasks does not contain a definition for WorkTasks...

I am sure I am making a stupid rookie mistake. Can anyone help?

And if I am doing this totally wrong then just say. This is my very first attempt at this.

Comment: Property `taskslist` is type of `List<BaseTask>` so your iterating through a collection of `BaseTask` objects. typeof `BaseTask` does not contain a property named  `Company` or `UserName`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - thanks for your comment. I can see that is the issue with my rubbish attempt, but I can access the data through the inspector  in debug mode so I assume that there is some way to access it in the view, I just can't see how.

Comment: Easiest way of course would be to have 2 lists, one for `WorkTasks` and one for `HomeTasks`. Other wise you going to have to test each task in the view - e.g.  `if (item is WorkTasks)` and then cast it to to the correct type - e.g. `var t = (WorkTask)item;` and then access it - `@t.Company`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Thanks for this. I don't understand the downvotes. I tried @(WorkTasks)item.Company, but this did not work, but doing it your way with the var t=... works spot on. I am displaying different html for each so I need an if anyway. I am sure there is a more MVC way to do this, but this is great for now. Thank you so much

Comment: It would have needed to be `@((WorkTasks)item).Company` - i.e. you casting `item` (not the `Company` property of item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems overly complicated and lacks using some of the awesome advantages of MVC (granted I didn't real the *entire* post).  So here is some example code based losely off most of your models:

Simplier model:

```
public class TasksViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<TaskBase> Tasks {get; set; }
}

// Removed (s), it's best practice to only use s on collections
public class WorkTask : BaseTask
{
  public String Company { get; set; }
}

// Removed (s), it's best practice to only use s on collections
public class HomeTask : BaseTask
{
  public String UserName{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller populates model:

```
public MyController
{
  public ActionResult MyTasksAction()
  {
    var model = new TasksViewmodel()
    model.Tasks = db.GetTasks();
    return View(model);  // Looks for MyTasksAction.cshtml
  }
}
```

View (MyTasksAction.cshtml):

```
@model TasksViewModel

<div>
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Tasks)
</div>
```

Boom done...  ([sorta kidding, but not really, if you're into that sorta thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h14nVtDy-Dg))

By default the DisplayFor will do it's work ([thats a story for another time](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)) but it won't find a display template matching that type, so it uses it's own internal Object display template which is smart enough to loop through all the items auto-magically.  As it loops through the items it calls `DisplayFor()` on each item so as long as you have:

> /Views/MyController/DisplayTemplates/WorkTask.cshtml
>
> /Views/MyController/DisplayTemplates/HomeTask.cshtml

**OR**

> /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/WorkTask.cshtml
>
> /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/HomeTask.cshtml

those templates are called with the current model in the loop... because Display templates are based on the type (IE a display template for `string` would be `string.cshtml`; `worktask` would be `worktask.cshtml`, etc).  Those templates might look like:

WorkTask.cshtml

```
@model WorkTask     
<div>
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Description)</br>
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Company)</br>
</div>
```

HomeTask.cshtml

```
@model HomeTask     
<div>
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Description)</br>
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserName)</br>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. I clearly have some reading to do, but this definitely points me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you again. This took me about 20 minutes to change to this method and it is so much better, I still don't understand the comments re splitting in to two lists rather than inheriting. I am displaying them in a list in date order. I can't see how I would do that with this method and two lists, but with your method it works fantastic the way I have arranged the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer the question directly cause its a learning experience. Although, I would probably split it into two separate lists as suggested by other people. The general rule of thumb is one view (.cshtml thing) per one model, although at work we built a ViewEngine to render `List'TBase'` so lol.

```
namespace SOAnswer0729.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public RedirectToRouteResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Tasks");
    }
    public ActionResult Tasks()
    {
        var tasks = new Tasks();
        var model = tasks.getAllTasks();
        return View(model);
    }
}

public class Tasks
{

    public List<BaseTask> taskslist { get; set; }
    public Tasks()
    {
        taskslist = getAllTasks();
    }

    public List<BaseTask> getAllTasks()
    {
        //get data
        List<BaseTask> tempTasks = new List<BaseTask>();

        tempTasks.AddRange(DataRepository.WorkSeedData);            
        tempTasks.AddRange(DataRepository.HomeSeedData);

        return tempTasks;
    }

    public enum TaskType
    {
        Undefined = 0,
        WorkTask = 1,
        HomeTask = 2
    }

}

public static class DataRepository
{

    public static List<WorkTask> WorkSeedData = new List<WorkTask>() { 
        new WorkTask() { id = 1, Company = "MSFT", Description = "Write Code" },
        new WorkTask() { id = 2, Company = "ATT", Description = "Sell Service" },
        new WorkTask() { id = 3, Company = "XFTY", Description = "Retain Customers" }
    };

    public static List<HomeTask> HomeSeedData = new List<HomeTask>() {
        new HomeTask() { id = 11, UserName = "Jim", Description = "Make Keys" },
        new HomeTask() { id = 12, UserName = "Bob", Description = "Find Keys" },
        new HomeTask() { id = 13, UserName = "Alice", Description = "Intecept Keys" }
    };
}

public class BaseTask
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}

public class WorkTask : BaseTask
{
    public String Company { get; set; }
}

public class HomeTask : BaseTask
{
    public String UserName { get; set; }
}
```

}

VIEW

```
@using SOAnswer0729.Controllers;
@model IEnumerable<BaseTask>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>Company / Name </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @{ if (item is WorkTask)
            {
              <text>@(((WorkTask)item).Company)</text>
            }
            else if (item is HomeTask)
            {
                <text>@(((HomeTask)item).UserName).</text>
            }
        }
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```